# Are the voters of comments recorded?

Tags: support, comments, comment-voting

I heard that sometimes mods can know the voters of answers, is there anyone who can know who voted comments? Is there a fixed amount of rep one needs to have access to either information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is being recorded somewhere, but only SE developers with direct access to the database can see who really upvoted a comment. (and obviously, they won't do it without a good reason)

Same goes for questions and answers: moderators do **not** have access  to see who voted, only to see *patterns*, which can help detect serial voters. Only SE devs can dig and see who actually voted.

You might be confused with flags: post flags and comment flags are visible to moderators, including who cast them.